# TFS 2010- Sharepoint 2010 Project Portal

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I have TFS 2010 integrated with share-point 2010, inside the project portal i try to add a new task but there is no start date neither due date ?

is that normal ? how can i add these fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal I'm afraid, the web page view of a Work Item is usually identical to the view of the same item in Visual Studio. For some reason these fields are hidden.

You have 2 options. You can change the Work Item template on your Team Project so that these fields are not hidden, or you can use the Office integration features of Team Explorer.

To [edit the template](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/11/06/Modifying-Work-Item-Types-in-TFS-2010.aspx) you'll need the [TFS 2010 power tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963).

To use Office integration you'll need Team Explorer installed, plus either Excel 2007+ or MS Project 2007+. Project automaticaly hooks in to the start and due date, with excel you can select which fields you want to view and sync with TFS